# Eclipse debugger looking in non-existent (and wrong) path for source files

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to debug my code in Eclipse (actually Atollic Studio) but I continually get a "can't find source file at `\directory_that_does_not_exist_on_my_machine\main.c`"

I've already attempted to change the source lookup path to the proper directories but haven't had any success - it continually searches the wrong directory. I've restarted Eclipse, and removed and then remade the debug configuration as well.

Edit: Running Windows 10 for what its worth

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. I had to add the path using the path mapping option under Debug Configurations -> Source -> Path Mapping.

For some reason, the debugger was deadset on searching /home/developers/.../file.c for the files so I had to map it to C:\Users\myusername\where_my_files_exist\file.c and everything seems to be working.